# Don't understand how a "while not" loop works

Tags: python

I am currently trying to learn python. I was going through Al Sweigart's *Automate the Boring stuff with Python*. In his example of `while` loops, he uses a `not` condition with his `while` loop (as shown in the code below).

```
name = ''
while not name != '':
    print('Enter your name:')
    name = input()
print('How many guests will you have?')
numOfGuests = int(input())
if numOfGuests !=0:
    print('Be sure to have enough room for all your guests.')
print('Done')
```

This code works fine. I am confused about how this works though. We set name to `''` (blank value) and then in the `while` loop we have `while not name !=''`. Why does this not work with `while name != ''`?

Comment: `not` inverts the condition. `while not name != ''` is the same as `while name == ''`

Comment: It may be useful to understand that `not` is an operator in Python (a unary operator, like the `-` in `-5`). It can be part of the condition in a `while` loop, but it is not part of the loop syntax directly.

Comment: To be clear, his example says `while not name:` and says that's equivalent (in this case) to `while not name != '':`

Comment: FWIW, that is a terrible way to write that condition. Even if you understand it, the double negation takes thrice as long to correctly comprehend at best and leads to new Stack Overflow posts at worst.

Comment: Double negatives *are* confusing. If this is the exact example code, I think it's a bad example. `while name == ''` is much more understandable indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop will only loop as long as the condition after it remains true. Putting a `not` before the condition inverts it. `not True == False`, `not False == True`

`while not name != ''` will loop as long as `(not (name != ''))` is True.

Answer (score 0):

The not operator will invert your condition so the while loop condition is logically equivalent to saying, while name is equal to the empty string ''. This is because you have the statement, `name != ''`, and then you use the `not` operator on it which inverts it. This is so the while loop will continue to request the user for an input name that does not equal ''.